# Check how close you are to limit

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running a number of queries on Google Big Query and I would like to know how close I am to having spent the free tier limit of going through free terabyte of readable data.

Comment: Check this https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#credits it should give you all the information you need. If you have a more specific question please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: It would appear you cannot check how close are you to having spent the 1 TB of the free monthly data usage allowance. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58984105)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways to view your current quota limits in the Google Cloud Console:

1) Using the ‘Quotas’ page, which gives you a list of all your project's quota usage and limits information through the following navigation.

- Console Dashboard > Navigation Menu Icon (top left corner)
- IAM & Admin > Quotas

You may also access directly to the same page through the given link [1].

On the Quotas page you can filter the data by 'Quota Type', 'Service', 'Metric' and 'Location' to find the ‘Current Usage’ vs your quota 'Limit’.

2)  Using the ‘Console’, which gives you quota information for a particular API, including resource usage over time [2].

For any further detailed information regarding ‘Quotas’ please refer to the documentation [3].

- [1] https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=bigquery.googleapis.com
- [2] https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard
- [3] https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota